# UITableView, heighForRowAtIndex is not returning the height I want

Tags: ios, uitableview, height

I have the following implemented:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ return 75; }
```

The height is displaying properly only when it receives json serialization data. When it is getting no data, it displays the height as the default height. What is overriding this method?

Comment: You need to set the `rowHeight` property of the table view (either in code or in IB).  If you don't set it, you get a default height according to the documentation:`If you do not explicitly set the row height, UITableView sets it to a standard value.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want every row to be the same height then don't use the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Instead, set the table view row height once, in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 75;
```

This will work for all rows, not just the ones with data.

Answer (score 0):

The method heightForRowAtIndexPath only called when numberOfRowsInSection return value > 0. In this case what you saw is the default empty table view.

I think in the case you have no data, you should hide all the default empty row by this line of code in viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

And show and empty Label of Image to let user know no data returned. Example:

```
- (void) requestData {
  // Your request data code
  // When request data complete, check and show that label
  self.labelNoData.hidden = (arrayData.count == 0);
}
```